# surface metric in normal coordinates and gaussian curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a $2$-dimensional Riemannian manifold.
Let $p\in M$ and let $r>0$ be such that the ball $B(p,r)\subset M$ is
geodesic.
Further let $(r,\theta)$ be polar coordinates in $T_p M$.

- > Show that the pullback metric $(\exp_p|B(0,r))^* g$ can be
  > represented in the form $dr^2+f(r,\theta)d\theta^2$ for a smooth
  > function $f>0$.

  **My solution**:
  Let $\overline g=(\exp_p|B(0,r))^* g$.
  Under the identification $T_0(T_p M)\cong T_p M$, the differential
  $d\exp_p:T_0(T_p M)\rightarrow T_p M$ is the identity map
  and $g_{xy}=\delta_{xy}$ in the coordinate chart
  $(x,y)=v\mapsto\exp_p(v)$.
  We compute
  \begin{align*}
    \overline g_{xx}+\overline g_{yy}
    &=\left(
      \left(
      \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}
      \right)^2
      +\left(
      \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}
      \right)^2
      \right)g_{rr}
      +2\left(
      \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\frac{\partial x}{\partial\theta}
      +\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\frac{\partial y}{\partial\theta}
      \right)g_{r\theta}
      +\left(
      \left(
      \frac{\partial x}{\partial\theta}
      \right)^2
      +\left(
      \frac{\partial y}{\partial\theta}
      \right)^2
      \right)g_{\theta\theta} \\
    &=(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)g_{rr}
      +2r(\sin\theta\cos\theta-\cos\theta\sin\theta)g_{r\theta}
      +r^2(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)g_{\theta\theta}.
  \end{align*}
  Therefore
  $$\overline g=dr^2+r^2 d\theta^2.$$
- > Show that the Gauss curvature of $(M,g)$ at a point $x=\exp_p(r,\theta)$
  > fulfills
  > $$K(x)\geq-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}f(r,\theta)/f(r,\theta).$$

It seems to me that I've done the first part incorrectly, because I would think that $f$ somehow depends on $\theta$, or does it not do that because that dependence is absorbed by the exponential map?

I'm not sure how I would go about the second part.
I know the formula
$$K=g(\nabla_y\nabla_x\partial_x-\nabla_x\nabla_y\partial_x,\partial_y)/\det g,$$
but I'm still struggling with that formula.

It looks straight forward if I can compute the covariant derivatives, but I'm struggling with those...

Comment: $d\exp_p$ is the identity only at one point, the origin. The first question is just Gauss lemma.